# Problem remotely managing Exchange Server 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, winrm

I can't connect to the instance of exchange server 2010 through EMC on the local machine running w2k8 r2. I've checked all the default website bindings, the kerberos auth and WSMan are set to native type in powershell and I still get this error message.

Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message:

> The WS-Management  service does not
>   support the request.

It was running the command 'Discover-ExchangeServer -UseWIA $true -suppresserror $true'

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're trying to remotely manage an Exchange 2010 server using an EMC running on another machine; is this right?

Some things you should check:

- Is your EMC patched to the same level as the Exchange server?
- Is the machine you're running EMC on in the same domain as the Exchange server?
- Do you have proper DNS resolution for the AD domain on your machine?
- Are you logged in as a domain user?
- Does your user account have proper privileges to manage the Exchange server?
- Are the two machines in the same subnet, or there is some routing in the middle? If some router is involved, is it configured to forward all traffic or is it doing some firewalling too? Can you connect to the Exchange server using other protocols, like Remote Desktop?
- Speaking of firewalls, how is Windows Firewall configured on the Exchange server? If you're unsure about this (Exchange uses ***lots*** of ports), try turning it off and see if things start working.

Comment: I shall check your list in the morning when I get into the office. Thanks for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue which is resolved by changing  IP address in the IIS exhcange virtual Directories .